# Как считать из аргументов адрес?

Tags: linux, bash

Входные данные скрипта: имя, аргумент(-n) и адрес папки, в которой он проверяет количество файлов. Если не был задан адрес папки - проверяется папка текущая. Так вот, подскажите, какой командой считывается адрес папки? `getopts` позволяет вроде как считывать типа -n, но не позволяет /user/home/Desktop/test/

Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под адресом папки ? Вам нужен путь к текущему каталогу или к какому то другому ?

Comment: @Mike , к какому-то другому

Answer (score 1):

```
arg="$1"
if [[ "$arg" = "-n" ]]; then
  FOLDERNAME="$2"
else
  echo "Bad input!"; exit -1;
fi

if [[ -z "$FOLDERNAME" ]]; then
  FOLDERNAME="." # или что вам нужно
fi
echo "$FOLDERNAME"
```

Или, в общем случае:

```
arg="$1"; shift

while [ "$1" ]; do

  case "$arg" in
    -n) FOLDERNAME="$1"; shift;;

    -f) FILENAME="$1"; shift;;

    # ... другие ключи ...

    *)  echo "Bad input!"; exit -1;;

  esac

done

if [[ -z "$FOLDERNAME" ]]; then
  FOLDERNAME="." # или что вам нужно
fi

echo "$FOLDERNAME"
```

P.S. Тут есть один момент, если скрипт запущен так: `./some.sh -n -f`, то имя папки окажется `"-f"`. Но с этим уже самостоятельно разбирайтесь :)

Как вариант - всё-таки использовать `getopts` с обязательным аргументом, где какое-то специальное значение будет исполнять роль "по умолчанию":

```
while getopts "n:" arg; do
  case "$arg" in
    -n) FILENAME="$OPTARG";;
  esac
done

if [[ "$FILENAME" = "some_special_value" ]]; then
    FILENAME="что-то_по_умолчанию"
fi
```

Comment: `while [ $# -ge 1 ]; do`, `esac \n shift` (\n -- next line) тогда не надо дублировать, позапускайте ваши скрипты вот так `sh -efu myscript.sh`. Много нового узнаете.

Comment: @0andriy, что мне надо я и так знаю. Отвечайте тому, кто задал вопрос.

Comment: Ну положим, грубить не стоит, мой комментарий оставлен в надежде, что отвечающий на вопрос будет это делать немного лучше.